# How to match the color of a rgl mesh and the color of a line on this mesh?

Tags: r, 3d, mesh, rgl

When you plot a **rgl** mesh and a line on the surface on this mesh with the same color, the line is visible:

```r
library(rgl)
shade3d(cube3d(), color = "cyan")
lines3d(rbind(c(-1,-1,-1), c(1,1,-1)), color="cyan")
```

How to get a perfect matching between the colors, so that the line is not visible? ([motivation here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76531722/1100107)).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is not with the color, but with a parameter related to the directional lighting. For example, `light3d(theta=0, phi=0)` will give you a very "washed out" cube, but the line will be invisible.

**Example 1:**

```
shade3d(cube3d(), color = "cyan") 
wire3d(cube3d(), color = "black") 
# light3d(theta=0, phi=0)
lines3d(rbind(c(-1,-1,-1), c(1,1,-1)), color="cyan")
par3d(userMatrix = rotationMatrix(pi*1.3, pi*1.3, 0, 0))
```

[image: Cube with directional light effects.]

**Example 2:**

```
shade3d(cube3d(), color = "cyan") 
wire3d(cube3d(), color = "black") 
light3d(theta=0, phi=0)
lines3d(rbind(c(-1,-1,-1), c(1,1,-1)), color="cyan")
par3d(userMatrix = rotationMatrix(pi*1.3, pi*1.3, 0, 0))
```

[image: Cube without directional light effects.]

Comment: Yes, but I want the ordinary lighting. I think this has to do with the specular or the ambient color or the emission color.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `lit = FALSE` when you draw the cube, the line will be invisible.  You also won't be able to see the difference between the faces of the cube, so this isn't usually an acceptable solution.

You can specify `lit = TRUE` for the line, but `rgl` appears to ignore it when drawing lines.  This is because lines don't have well defined normals, and the normals are critical in computing the lighting. I suppose you could specify the normals explicitly to match the normals to the face, but as far as I recall `rgl` doesn't support this.

One alternative is to draw polygons instead of lines; they'll have defined normals, and if they happen to match the normals to the face they are drawn on, they should blend in.

Edited to add:

One way to get `lit` to apply to lines is to draw a polygon with `front = "lines", back = "lines"`.  However, this doesn't usually make it blend in, and I suspect my suggestion of drawing polygons wouldn't be easy to get right either.

The problem is that in `cube3d()` each vertex is shared by 3 faces.  If you use the default `smooth = TRUE`, it computes the normal by averaging the normals of the 3 faces.  With `smooth = FALSE`, it just picks one face.  So if you want to
get it to blend in, you need to specify the normals at each vertex to match what is calculated by `rgl` for that vertex.
Here's an example that does that:

```
open3d()
triangles3d(rbind(c(-1,-1,-1), c(-1, -0.999, -1), c(1,1,-1)),
            color="cyan", front="lines", back="lines",
            polygon_offset = 1, 
            normals = rbind(c(-1,-1,-1), c(-1, -1, -1), c(1,1,-1)))
shade3d(cube3d(), color = "cyan")
```

You won't see the lines at all; to convince yourself that they are being drawn, change one of the colours.  (NB:  The triangle is now extremely thin, but when I made the it even thinner, it appeared the graphics hardware stopped treating it as a polygon, and it didn't work.)